# Set value in object by path and flatten again with objects and arrays

Tags: javascript

Im totally clueless how to build this. I am not even sure it is even possible and I've been scratching my head for way too long now.

Lets say I have an object:

```
const myObj = {
    simple: "test",
    nested: {
        obj: "alright"
    }
}
```

Now I have found a function that lets me set a value anywhere by specifying a path in that tree. If a key is not already existing in that object, it will be created:

```
const set = (obj: any, path: any, val: any) => {
    const keys = path.split(".");
    const lastKey = keys.pop();
    const lastObj = keys.reduce((obj: any, key: any) => obj[key] = obj[key] || {}, obj);
    lastObj[lastKey] = val;
};
```

Example:

```
set(myObj, "nested.another.iCanEvenGoDeeper", "very deep value");
```

Result:

```
const myObj = {
    simple: "test",
    nested: {
        obj: "alright",
        another: {
            iCanEvenGoDeeper: "very deep value"
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good, but now its required that I can also define a path like this to dynamically build arrays. So that I can call these:

```
set(myObj, "nested.myArray[0].propInsideArrayElement", "first element")
set(myObj, "nested.myArray[1].propInsideArrayElement", "second element")
```

that will result in an object that looks like this:

```
{
    simple: "test",
    nested: {
        obj: "alright",
        myArray: [
            { propInsideArrayElement: "first element" },
            { propInsideArrayElement: "second element" }
        ]
    }
}
```

It needs to be recursive and work with all scenarios, but I am like I said clueless on if it is even possible. Is there by any chance some utility scripts out there that does this already? If not, can anyone point me in the right direction?

In a next step, I would like to flatten the object to have a one dimensional object again, for the last example it would then look like this:

```
flatten(myObj);
```

would then turn to

```
{
    "simple": "test",
    "nested.obj": "alright",
    "nested.myArray[0].propInsideArrayElement": "first element",
    "nested.myArray[1].propInsideArrayElement": "second element"
}
```

Comment: You can use something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-value

Comment: Sadly it doesnt work with arrays. You can pass an array instead of a string path, but you cannot set a value to an index in an array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have totally reworked the deepSet function now. It now supports multiple arrays and gaps in the arrays etc. I think this covers now every usecase. In the end it was way easier to figure the logic out when I started over without the reduce function

```
export const deepSet = (obj: any, path: string, val: any) => {
    path = path.replaceAll("[", ".[");
    const keys = path.split(".");

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        let currentKey = keys[i] as any;
        let nextKey = keys[i + 1] as any;
        if (currentKey.includes("[")) {
            currentKey = parseInt(currentKey.substring(1, currentKey.length - 1));
        }
        if (nextKey && nextKey.includes("[")) {
            nextKey = parseInt(nextKey.substring(1, nextKey.length - 1));
        }

        if (typeof nextKey !== "undefined") {
            obj[currentKey] = obj[currentKey] ? obj[currentKey] : (isNaN(nextKey) ? {} : []);
        } else {
            obj[currentKey] = val;
        }

        obj = obj[currentKey];
    }
};
```

Comment: For anyone coming across this, a more concise approach is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78216954/221869

Answer (score 1):

Looks interesting :)

Here is an example for array support based on your own code.

flatten the object is also included (Using recursive calls)

```js
const myObj = {
    simple: "test",
    nested: {
        obj: "alright"
    }
}
const getTypeVal = (currentIndex, length, val) => {
  
}
const set = (obj, path, val) => {
    path = path.replace('[', '.[')
    const keys = path.split(".");
    const lastKey = keys.pop();
    let lastObj = keys.reduce((obj, key, currentIndex) => {
      if(key.includes('[')) {
          return obj[key.substring(1, key.length-1)]
       }
       if(obj[key] && obj[key].length && (keys[currentIndex+1] && keys[currentIndex+1].includes('['))) {
          let nextKey = keys[currentIndex+1] 
          nextKey = nextKey.substring(1, nextKey.length-1)
          !obj[key][nextKey] && obj[key].push({})
       }
       return obj[key] = obj[key] || ((keys[currentIndex+1] && keys[currentIndex+1].includes('[')) ? [{}] : keys[currentIndex+1] ? {} : val)
    }
    , obj);
        lastObj[lastKey] = val;
};
const flatternObj = (obj, result = {}, key ='') =>{
  if(Array.isArray(obj)) {
     obj.forEach((d,i) => {
       result = flatternObj(d, result, key + `[${i}]`)
     })
  }
  else if(typeof obj === 'object') {
    for (const i of Object.keys(obj)) {
       result = flatternObj(obj[i], result, key ? key + `.${i}` : `${i}`)
    }
  }
  else {
     result[key] = obj
  }
  return result;
}


set(myObj, "nested.myArray[0].propInsideArrayElement", "first element")
set(myObj, "nested.myArray[0].propInsideArrayElement2", "first element - 2 ")
set(myObj, "nested.myArrayTwo[0]", 'test')
set(myObj, "nested.myArray[1].propInsideArrayElement", "second element")
set(myObj, "nested.myArray[2]", 'test')
console.log(myObj)

console.log(flatternObj(myObj))
```

Comment: Amazing! I think the flatten is exactly what I needed. Also the set looks good, however I noticed that when you set a value to an array directly, means no sub object it assigns it to an object with keys [0] for example. Try this one: set(obj, "another.test.arr[0]", 222). Im ashamed btw, I'm trying to do the set since yesterday and couldnt get it to work properly

Comment: yes need another condition to handle that. let me modify again

Comment: appreciate it a lot, also the flatten seems to need it. Otherwise it adds a dot before the brackets [

Comment: That is very good. Yeah I think I dont need to have arrays in arrays. Usually we will only have one level of array. Thanks a lot, you dont understand how much headache you just saved me, if you want I can credit you in the readme of my project.

Comment: Of course, Thanks

Comment: For completeness, you could change the !obj[key][nextKey] && obj[key].push({}) to if (!obj[key][nextKey]) {
        obj[key][nextKey] = {};
      }. Then it is possible to have gaps in the array and also arrays inside of arrays are possible :)